# Troubleshooting PHP $_POST from Android Studio

Tags: php, android, sql, database, post

thanks in advance for your time. Here is the situation:

I am trying to post some data from my Android application. First, consider my PHP code (the login credentials are correct, trust me :D)

```html
<?php
$db_name = "op-users";
$mysql_username = "******";
$mysql_password = "******";
$server_name = "***.***.***.***";

$con = mysqli_connect($server_name, $mysql_username, $mysql_password,
$db_name);

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$email = $_POST["email"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO users (username, password,
email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $username, $password, $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Critically, when I *hardcode* in values for $username, $password, and $email, it works perfectly, entering those values into my database. This would seem to indicate that this PHP is working as intended, but not receiving the values from the $_POST statements.

Consider also the following Wireshark capture, where it is seen that my app is in fact sending out the POST information.
[WIRESHARK CAPTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFNsF.png)

In sum, the PHP works, but doesn't seem to be receiving the POST requests. The app sends the POST data, but the PHP page isn't picking up on the posted data. By the way, I know the app is successfully contacting register.php because as I said, when I would hardcode in the values, registering on the app would cause the hardcoded values to be saved to the databse.

Can anybody recommend a troubleshooting avenue? Thanks!

Comment: Just to debug the issue, check your form's `method` attribute, is it `GET` or `POST`?

Comment: I really advice you to encode posting data into a JSON, its very easy, very secure, and you wouldn't waste your time trying to debug things like that.

Comment: I do have Method.POST. I wonder if there is a way to confirm that this is applying... but the Wireshark clip would seem to suggest that it is POSTing, wouldn't you think?

Comment: It just seems like there are a billion of these types of tutorials or examples online, and none of them are working for me and this is the symptom every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just want to debrief on this. Turns out it that my GoDaddy server was running Windows, which was preventing my POST array from getting though. I realized this after I uploaded my .php files to a different server, running Linux, and it worked perfectly. So GoDaddy went ahead and migrated me over to a Linux server and it works now.

In short, my problem was some invisible setting running on a Windows server far, far away. If you are experiencing these same symptoms, try using a Linux server.

Comment: So in fact you still do not know what exactly was set wrong. Windows or Linux should not really matter here.

Comment: Correct, I do not know what was wrong. But I read somewhere that GET and POST requests were DISABLED by default on Windows Servers, which 100% explains what the symptoms were.

Comment: Maybe. Luckily my experience with Windows as servers is limited. However if GET request were disabled nothing would show up except error from client/browser (when you type url in browser and hit enter -> this is GET request). If POST would was blocked, you would see no response from server when sending your POST neither but error from client. these worked so your problem was elsewhere (perhaps in PHP POST related settings).

Answer (score 0):

Please put this on your php file to confirm you're receiving the proper values:

`print_r($_POST);`

Comment: I thought about doing that, but since no browser is really accessing the page, I wouldn't be able to see anything, right? In other words, the app is connecting to the URL in the background, so I would have no way of seeing what displayed... know what I mean?

Comment: @Treadle, how about file_put_contents("fileToSave", json_encode($_POST)); That way you can check your data being received.

Comment: Just tried, and the page won't load when I add this line... I didn't forget to change the file name to test.txt and upload that file to the server. Strange. It would be really nice to see the contents of POST though. That would be key.

Comment: `throw new Exception($_POST);`
Then look to your logs :)

Comment: I will try this now, but I need to look up how to set that up in PHP. Is it as simple as adding that line after the line that is causing the problem?

Comment: Yes. Then if you're using apache2:
`tail -f /var/log/apache2/*.log`

If you're using nginx:
`tail -f /var/log/nginx/*.log`

Comment: First it gave a 301 (redirect) then it gave you the 500 Error code (Internal Server Error) probably because we thrown the error forcing to write down the $_POST content. Look the text that was after this one you pasted, the $_POST content should be there.

Comment: You really should not post sensitive information like this to public. Btw, put the file_put_contents as very first line of your PHP script. It should work, and btw, your don't need to create a file in which you are gonna save; if it doesn't exist, file_put_contents() function will create it on its own.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Borna. I'll try putting that as the first line. And Andre, none of the POST information was in the log file. By the way, thank you both for giving me pointers.

Comment: Even as the first line, it crashes the site. I am so fed up with this. Something clearly is messed up with the POST. Maybe there's some setting on Godaddy I have to change.

Comment: just put this after the "<?php"

`echo json_encode($_POST); die();`

and then on your app check the response you get.

Comment: My app isn't getting any response. I have to stop doing this before I lose my mind. I'll check the thread in the morning. Thanks again.